# Winston logger exitOnError: false still exits

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have a pretty basic `winston` setup:

`src/appSetup.js`

```
const logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      timestamp: true,
    }),
  ],
  exitOnError: false,
});

module.exports.logger = logger;
```

Which I use something like this:

```
    const logger = require('../src/appSetup').logger;

    const concatenater = (string1) => {
      if (condition-check) {
        // do something
      }

      logger.error('error message');
      return ''; // this is necessary as tests expects empty string on if-condition fail
    };
```

Right now `logger.error` exits the code block and hence nothing is returned. I did add `exitOnError: false,` in the logger definition but it still exits.

If I swap `logger.error('error message');` with `console.error('error message');` everything works as expected.

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: How to you import `logger`?

Comment: @robertklep Updated post to include that.

Comment: FWIW, `exitOnError` is not related to calling `logger.error()`. Also, it cannot "exit the code block"; what _could_ happen is that, for some reason, `logger.error` isn't a function and trying to call it throws an exception that for some reason gets swallowed (which is relatively easy to do when it's used within the context of a promise chain, for instance). In other words: I think it's related to the context in which `concatenater` is being called.

Comment: hmm I am using `logger.info` and `logger.error` at other places and that works just fine, so it is a valid function

Comment: Actually I just did a `console.log(logger);` after `const logger = require('../src/appSetup').logger;` and I get `undefined` so something is not right in the way its exported

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the code that you're posting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended by solving this issue but abstracting the `logger` function outside of the scope of the `appSetup.js` file, to avoid any callback hell. Just exported it as a regular module and imported wherever was needed.